# Sequelize Credentials for Deploying Node.js App to Heroku

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku, deployment, sequelize.js

I am currently learning Node.js (with Express, Postgres, Sequelize) and have a very simple (API) app running locally (it's working, tried with Postman) I now want to deploy to Heroku. I have some basic Heroku knowledge as I've used Rails in the past, but I am stuck with some things Rails handles behind the scenes.

I've set up a config.js file with some production credentials generated when running `npx sequelize-cli init`, I've updated my local settings (this works!) but what do I need to add as my production credentials? Do I need to provide them on my own? Or are those provided by Heroku?

Please note — I've already setup my pipeline and app as well as Postgres on Heroku but when trying to connect to my app via the cli, e.g. `heroku run bash --app name-of-my-app` and running `npx sequelize-cli db:create` it gives me the following error:

```
Loaded configuration file "config/config.js".
Using environment "production".
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at Object.removeTicks (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/utils.js:347:12)
    at Object.quoteIdentifier (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator/helpers/quote.js:50:35)
    at PostgresQueryGenerator.quoteIdentifier (/app/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/query-generator.js:891:24)
    at getCreateDatabaseQuery (/app/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/commands/database.js:77:50)
    at Object.exports.handler (/app/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/commands/database.js:45:17)
```

Further notes:

- I am using Node 14.0.0 and sequelize `6.3.0`
- I've added `"engines": { "node": "14.x" }` to my `package.json`
- I don't have a procfile as Heroku states it's not needed anymore
- My app entrypoint is `app.js`

Answer (score 0):

Putting this up here, in case someone else is having similar troubles:

Just figured it out, it's actually pretty straight forward but I was a bit confused by the default `config.js` setup provided when running `npx sequelize-cli init`.

this is what my production settings look like:

```
  production: {
    use_env_variable: 'DATABASE_URL',
    dialect: 'postgres'
  }
```